# how to apply a function which takes the caller as its arugment

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am trying to run np's correlation function on the dataframe column by column, yet the correlation that I want to run on is the series itself. For instance, say df is our dataframe and ts is the first column of df. I want to call `np.correlate(ts, ts, method="full")`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5]], index=range(5), columns=list("ab"))

def acf(R):
    """
    Calcualte the auto correlation function of a series with lag 0 up to the length
    of the series. 
    """
    y = R - R.mean()
    result = y.apply(np.correlate, (y, "full"))
    result = result[len(result)//2:]
    result /= result[0]
    return result

acf(df)

NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

What should I do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas.Series` objects tend to work well with `numpy` functions so defining your function as

```
def acf(R):
    """
    Calcualte the auto correlation function of a series with lag 0 up to the length
    of the series. 
    """
    y = R - R.mean()
    result = np.correlate(y, y, 'full')
    result = result[len(result)//2:]
    result /= result[0]
    return result
```

And then applying it to the `DataFrame` with `df.apply(acf)` should work.

```
In [4]: import numpy as np

In [5]: import pandas as pd
   ...: def acf(R):
   ...:     """
   ...:     Calcualte the auto correlation function of a series with lag 0    up to the length
   ...:     of the series. 
   ...:     """
   ...:     y = R - R.mean()
   ...:     result = np.correlate(y, y, 'full')
   ...:     result = result[len(result)//2:]
   ...:     result /= result[0]
   ...:     return result
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5]], index=range(5), columns=list("ab"))
   ...: 

In [6]: df.apply(acf)
Out[6]: 
     a    b
0  1.0  1.0
1  0.4  0.4
2 -0.1 -0.1
3 -0.4 -0.4
4 -0.4 -0.4
```

Comment: Thanks! This is actually the first approach comes to my mind, but somehow I got an error implementing it. It works now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How's this:

```
def acf(R, ref_col='a'):
    """
    Calcualte the auto correlation function of a series with lag 0 up to the length
    of the series. 
    """
    y = R - R.mean()
    result = pd.DataFrame([np.correlate(i, R[ref_col], "full") for _,i in R.iteritems()], index=R.columns).T
    result = result[len(result)//2:]
    result /= result.iloc[0,:]
    return result

acf(df)
```

Comment: This is awesome, thanks @dmvianna. It directly addresses my issue.